# sharepoint 2010 excel services - facing problems editing excel

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have uploaded an excel into a document library and able to view it in the browser. 
I am not able to edit the excel in the browser.

I have a simple calculation on two cells. Even the regular worksheets without any calculations are not editable.

Any idea?

Comment: Please tell us the error you are receiving or what is actually happening. Are you not able to edit any excel file in the browser? Is the Excel Services Application properly configured?

Comment: I do not see any errors. Excel opens fine in the browser. I am able to open the excel documents but it is read only state (When I click on a cell to edit the cursor doesnt show up). I tried from different machines and it is not a browser problem. I have the admin rights on the site collection.

Comment: I am not able to edit any excel document with or without calculations. I have not done any specific configurations for the excel service to run. I went to the central admin site and noticed the excel services is running fine (loading the excel works fine). i tried it in different browsers on diff machines so it should not be a browser issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see **Edit in Browser** option you need to Activate the Office Web Apps feature in Site Collection Features. This should be done after doing the Office Web Apps installation on the SharePoint server farm.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

1. Make sure you're *editing* the document in the browser, not viewing it
   [image]
2. Make sure the document library is setup for excel documents
3. You might have to check the document out, but I haven't had to ever do this.

Please check back and let us know what your final resolution is.

Comment: I do not see the edit in browser option at all. I have full control on the document library. I did points 2 & 3 already.